# Help restore audio for another user after pulseaudio is killed

Tags: pulseaudio, systemd, jack

When i kill a pulseaudio server, after it respawns, clients from other accounts are unable to access the pulseaudio unix domain socket file even though it is there.

It only works after a reboot of the system. Anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

After 'pulseaudio --kill' command Pulseaudio will respawn in a different state:

1. Systemd pulseaudio.service fails (see `systemctl --user status pulseaudio`)
2. Server changes from unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native to just username
3. Pulseaudio modules 'module-x11-publish' and 'module-x11-xsmp'

Changes to server and modules can be seen in Pulseaudio System Tray - pasystray

to restart Pulseaudio use:

`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`